# RPM dependency error during build phase of RPM spec file

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

My purpose is to distribute an already build `libmy.so` as installable library through RPM.

Following is the snippet of the .spec file:

```
%define elX el5
%define arch x86_64

Name: my_rpm
Version: 1.0
Requires: <package name which installs libxx.so >

%prep

%define debug_package %{nil}

%build

%install

%files

%defattr(-, root, root)

/home/%{elX}/%{arch}/%{name}_%{version}/lib/libmy.so
```

At the time of compilation of `libmy.so`, I am linking it against `libxx.so` which is installed as part of another RPM.

While installing the RPM created as a part of above step 1, it gives following dependency error even if `libxx.so` is installed on the machine

```
$ rpm -ivh *rpm

error: Failed dependencies:

libxx.so()(64bit) is needed by *rpm
```

We have tried the following things.

During the analysis we observed that the path where `libxx.so` is located is not present in `ld.so.conf`. However, adding an entry of path where `libxx.so` is located did not help us.

Please let us know whether we need to perform any additional steps to remove this dependency error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you install, `rpm` is looking for an entry in the RPM database; it does not test for the file on the system or linkable.

What is the output of

```
$ rpm -q --whatprovides libXX.so
```

That will list which package provides libXX.so. If no package provides it, your RPM will have a dependency error. Remove libXX.so from the `Requires:` entry. If you're not manually specifying it, it may be detected automatically. In your spec file, you can set:

```
AutoReqProv: no
```

That will disable ALL automatic detection of `Requires:`.

http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-depend-auto-depend.html